# AWS Lambda: Does pricing depends on allocated memory or function rumtime memory?

Tags: aws-lambda

1. How can I know actual memory my aws lambda function is taking up?
2. If my running code takes 50MB out of allocated 128MB, does aws charge for 50MB or 1328MB?
3. What happens, if my function requires more than the allocated memory (may be for few events)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use [AWS Cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions.html) to monitor memory usage. Alternatively you can use a third party service such as [Dashbird](https://dashbird.io/). In either case you should be able to configure alerts in the case of excess usage or other behavior
2. AWS will charge you for the full 128 MB. You are billed for what is allocated on your behalf.
3. If you exceed your memory limits, the function call will be terminated. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

See also [Understanding and Controlling AWS Lambda Costs](https://serverless.com/blog/understanding-and-controlling-aws-lambda-costs/).

Answer (score 0):

You are charged for the allocated memory and not for the used memory.
Also if your required memory is greater than the allocated memory then the code will fail at runtime.

For AWS Lambda pricing details refer to the below link.

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

Comment: thanks @Suman, can you address my first question regarding checking the runtime memory.

Comment: Not sure if you can see actual memory consumed at runtime. What i did was give the minimum memory required and then test it first with all scenario . If all test cases pass then keep that memory size. Custom Cloud-watch events can be a solution.

Comment: @VenkatPapana You can look at the Cloudwatch logs which provide a REPORT line for each request and that details the amount of time and memory used by the Lambda function.